# Serve PDF file when printing a web-page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

With CSS we have the possibility of customising the look-and-feel of a webpage when the user decides to print a document.

To have more control on the layout, would it be possible to serve a PDF file?

A possible solution could consist in embedding a PDF file in a popup window and trigger the action using javascript.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, and your possible solution is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question, but I have a few thoughts.

First of all: **Yes, you can serve a .pdf file**

I would like to say however, that it only makes sense to do so if whatever you are serving is not dynamic, like a online newspaper or magazine.

An example of a site that serves PDFs is my personal favorite publication [Nature](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v507/n7491/full/nature13066.html)

---

[image]

---

They still use print styles in CSS however, and I highly reccommend you do so.